# Jquery not function

Tags: jquery, css

I have [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/6kugr3b9/2/). I am trying to hide contents of `heading1` when `heading2` is clicked and vice versa.

I actually have 10 heading sections overall and I need to show only one at a time. I feel I need to use jQuery's `.not()` for that, but I am not getting the result I want.
How do I do that?

```
not(this.siblings)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Notes:**

▶ First of all, you haven't had a jQuery version linked to your jsfiddle.

▶ Using **`.not()`** is completely inappropriate for your case.

---

**What you need to do is:**

- Remove the **`checked`** attribute from the cousins.
- Hide everything under the heading of the unchecked checkbox.
- Show everything under the heading of the checked checkbox.

**Code:**

```
$(".checkbox").on("change", function() {
   if (this.checked) {
      /* Cousins */
      $(this).parent().siblings().children(".checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
      $(this).parent().siblings().children(".one:nth-of-type(n+2)").css('display', 'none');

      /* This */
      $(this).siblings(".one:nth-of-type(n+2)").css('display', 'block');
   }
   else {
      $(this).siblings(".one:nth-of-type(n+2)").css('display', 'none');
   }
});
```

**Fiddle:** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6kugr3b9/5/).

**Snippet:**

```js
$(".checkbox").on("change", function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    /* Cousins */
    $(this).parent().siblings().children(".checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
    $(this).parent().siblings().children(".one:nth-of-type(n+2)").css('display', 'none');
    
    /* This */
    $(this).siblings(".one:nth-of-type(n+2)").css('display', 'block');
  }
  else {
    $(this).siblings(".one:nth-of-type(n+2)").css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```css
.one,
.two {
  display: block;
}

.one:nth-of-type(n+2) {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox:checked ~ .one {
  display: block;
}

.checkbox:checked ~ .one:nth-of-type(n+2):before {
  content: attr(data-label);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
  <span data-label="test" class="one">heading1</span>
  <span data-label="test" class="one">test2</span>
  <span data-label="test" class="one">test3</span>
  <span data-label="test" class="one">test4</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
  <span data-label="test" class="one">heading2</span>
  <span data-label="test" class="one">test2</span>
  <span data-label="test" class="one">test3</span>
  <span data-label="test" class="one">test4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: re-clicking on the heading is only removing the :before attribute not hiding the whole .one elements -

Comment: with your code - clicking on one of the headings will close already opened one - but clicking on the same opened heading will also need to close it - toggle the displays basically